# Netty: how to pass an object to a specific handler?

Tags: java, netty

I'm writing some http server by using Netty.

Let's imagine that I have something like this (in initializer, all handlers extends `ChannelInboundHandlerAdapter`):

```
// REST API handlers
pipeline.addLast(new CreateEventHandler());
pipeline.addLast(new GetEventHandler());
pipeline.addLast(new UpdateEventHandler());
pipeline.addLast("delete", new DeleteEventHandler());
```

My question is can I pass an object to a specific handler like this (for example, somewhere in `CreateEventHandler`):

```
ChannelInboundHandlerAdapter h = (ChannelInboundHandlerAdapter) ctx.pipeline().get("delete");
h.channelRead(ctx, msg);
```

If yes, is this a good way? Or I'm guaranteed to get some overhead or errors? Or I must pass an object through all handlers in the pipeline?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

This not a good way to design your application. The Netty [ChannelPipeline](https://netty.io/4.0/api/io/netty/channel/ChannelPipeline.html) defines a *sequence* of handlers, each of which may transform the data passing through it. Essentially, the incoming/outgoing data is passed through all the inbound/outbound handlers in the pipeline. It is not a "conditional dispatch" mechanism which is what you seem to be looking for.

It looks like you're building a REST service; all you need is a generic HTTP pipeline, and a *single* inbound handler which will dispatch to your application code based on HTTP method. Which means none of the handlers in your example (`GetEventHandler` etc) need to extend `ChannelInboundHandlerAdapter` - they can be simple Java classes that have no netty specific code. This will give you a nice separation between protocol and business logic as well.